# What is the best solution around unmerged files issues on an ssh server?

Tags: php, git, laravel, ssh

I have been fighting with my app in laravel.

I recently removed a package called Clockwork and deleted files and directories associated with it. In the laravel app under storage there was a folder called clockwork and in here you could see json files that were created as a cached object. In this folder there was a .gitignore file. I deleted the folder from storage.

Now when I push to the repo and do a git pull on the ssh server I get this error. The ssh server is running on Forge for laravel and deploy script is below:

```
A   app/Day.php
M   app/Http/Controllers/OffersController.php
A   app/Http/Controllers/VenueController.php
M   app/Http/Kernel.php
M   app/Http/routes.php
M   app/Offer.php
A   app/Type.php
A   app/Venue.php
M   composer.json
M   composer.lock
M   config/app.php
D   config/clockwork.php
M   config/database.php
A   database/seeds/DayTableSeeder.php
A   database/seeds/DaysPivotSeeder.php
M   database/seeds/OfferTableSeeder.php
A   database/seeds/OfferTypePivotSeeder.php
A   database/seeds/OfferTypeTableSeeder.php
A   database/seeds/VenueTableSeeder.php
A   env.example
A   env.production
M   readme.md
M   resources/views/home.blade.php
M   resources/views/offers/partials/_form.blade.php
A   resources/views/venues/create.blade.php
A   resources/views/venues/edit.blade.php
A   resources/views/venues/index.blade.php
A   resources/views/venues/partials/_form.blade.php
A   resources/views/venues/show.blade.php
U   storage/clockwork
D   storage/clockwork/.gitignore
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
```

Deploy script

```
cd /home/forge/default
git pull origin master
composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist
php artisan migrate --force
```

As you can see 'U' tells me it's unmerged but it's not actually there anymore so I cannot see what the issue is.

I have tried `git rm storage/clockwork` but I get this:

```
ls
app     clockwork   framework   logs

mdunbavan$ git rm clockwork
fatal: pathspec 'storage/clockwork' did not match any files
```

Can anyone shed some light onto this?

Comment: why don't you delete that file manually and try git pull again.

Comment: I did exactly that and it gave me the same issues

Comment: how about git checkout file_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have committed `storage/*` to git since it is a cache folder. You can remove it by doing:

```
git rm --cached storage/*
```